# What are the valid strings for the typeArg argument of the InputEvent constructor?

Tags: javascript, html, inputevent

From MDN [InputEvent()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/InputEvent/InputEvent) docs:

> `event = new InputEvent(typeArg, inputEventInit);`
>
> **typeArg** Is a DOMString representing the name of the event.

What are the valid "names?" I can't find any resources indicating this. I want to replicate a typing event for my tests.

Comment: There was a perfect answer on this question that is now gone. If the original poster wants to re-add that answer, I will wait 30 minutes before simply posting the answer myself.

Comment: @komali_2 I was wrong, it was inputType not typeArg. The types are listed in section 5.2, `input` and `beforeInput`.

Comment: Oh, haha, and I scrolled down by accident and thus thought you had linked the right one. Would you like to submit 5.2 so I can accept the answer?

Comment: Whilst wanting to know the answer to this is valid, if you're wanting to implement "fake" input events, I'd recommend using totally custom events with reasonable names that you document and have much more control over, rather than relying on this.

Comment: Can you clarify? What I'm trying to do is trigger an actual input event, i.e. getting text into a field and letting Vue.js know it happened.

Comment: Here's the question specific to what I'm trying to do in testing Vue.js https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48102171/how-do-i-force-input-to-an-input-field-managed-by-vue-for-testing/48102289#48102289

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is listed in [Section 5.2 of the Input Events Level 2 Specification](https://w3c.github.io/input-events/index.html#event-definitions) and are `input` and `beforeInput`. This is also listed in [Section 4.5.3 of the UI Events Specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/uievents/#events-input-types).

Comment: In testing `var input = new InputEvent('input');`, `input` evaluates to literally just Window. I have no idea anymore

Comment: @komali_2 What do you mean?

Comment: Try this: `var input = new InputEvent('hah');
console.log(input)`

Comment: @komali_2 I get `InputEvent { … }` in the Chrome console.

Answer (score 0):

the `InputEvent` is an *object* particularly inheriting all the properties that has to do with
*form*  events

which are : submit , change , input

so a use case would be revealing one of those *properties* of any of the **InputEvent** events

```
var input = document.getElementById("textarea") ;
 
input.addEventListener("input", function(e) {
  console.log(e.inputType) ; 
})
```

or in this case creating a new *custom input event* and fire it multiple times in a loop

```
var inputField = document.getElementById("textarea") ;
var newInput = new InputEvent("input") ; 

for (var i = 0 ; i < 10 ; i ++ ) {
  inputField.value += i + "\n" ; 
  inputField.dispatchEvent(newInput) ; 
  
}
```