# How do I force input to an input field managed by Vue for testing?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, input, vue.js

I want to test that a Vue component is properly parsing and saving data after an input field it is watching receives input.

The component looks like this:

```
<template>
<div>
   <form>
     <div :key="key" v-for="key in contexts" class="row">
        <div class="input-field">
          <input v-model="saved_contexts[key]" placeholder="" :id="key" type="text">
          <label :for="key">{{key}}</label>
        </div>
    </div>
   </form>
</div>
</template>
<script>
  export default {
    data(){
      return {saved_contexts: {}}
    }
  },
</script>
```

I have left out the code that fills the "contexts" array, please assume it's there and working.

I want to write a test that demonstrates that input to the input field will caused the `saved_contexts` object to be updated properly (that the right key name was updated with the right value).

I've tried simply

`const input = vm.$el.querySelector('#test');
input.text = 'hello';`

but am getting a `Attempted to assign to readonly property.` error.

I'm exploring dispatching input events, but I can't figure out how to do that with an included text to actual be put in to the input field.

Comment: This will not be reactive. https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Change-Detection-Caveats

Comment: Ok, so then what's the reactive way to use a test to test an input field?

Answer (score 0):

This should be what you're looking for:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <form>
      <div v-for="key in contexts" :key="key" class="row">
        <div class="input-field">
          <input v-model="saved_contexts[key]"
                 :id="key"
                 @change="logInput(key, saved_contexts[key])"
                 placeholder=""
                 type="text">
          <label>{{key}}</label>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
  export default {
    data() {
      return {
        contexts: [
          'one',
          'two',
          'three',
        ],
        saved_contexts: {},
      };
    },
    methods: {
      logInput(key, input) {
        console.log(`saved_contexts's key: '${key}', updated with input: '${input}'`);
        console.log(this.saved_contexts[key] === input);
        console.log(this.saved_contexts);
      },
    },
  };
</script>
```

Vue has some issues when manipulating the DOM directly, but here you have a logging function, which verifies that the input has been saved to the saved_contexts.

Comment: This caused the same error: `Attempted to assign to readonly property.
`

Comment: Hmm, I'll try a few things and get back to you soon.

Comment: No worries. At least noticed that "key in contexts" should probably be "key in saved_contexts".

Comment: Found your problem, sec. :)

Comment: I see why you'd think that, I probably left out some critical code. `contexts` is an array provided by props, and then `saved_contexts` is generated by input events based on whatever is inside `contexts` (input fields are generated based off that array)

Comment: Updated my answer, hopefully this helps with your issue!

Comment: Thank you for your effort. I'm still not sure how to actually trigger an input event using a test (like mocha + chai) :(

Comment: No problems. I'm pretty sure though, that what you're trying to do is not possible (at least no simple solution). I had a similar situation (though not a unit test), where I needed to fill an input field from outside the Vue app, I ended up exposing a method on the global window object, that could be accessed from the outside. This might be an option to "simulate" data input, but it will not be the same as a true unit test.

Comment: Oh  man, so how do people typically unit test their input-style components then? I hunted over the weekend and couldn't find anybody doing it.